# How to set overflow=auto for mat-expansion-panel-body when using angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to set overflow=auto for mat-expansion-panel-body when using angular?
I tried to put those codes in css file, but it didn't work.

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
  overflow: overlay;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using ng-deep like below;

```
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-body {
  /* styles here */
}
```